# How to check if two GPS-based A to B distances overlap / cross each other at any point?

Tags: php, geolocation, gps

I use the following function to check the distance between point A -> B:

```
function airDistance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

      $gps = $lon1 - $lon2;
      $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($gps));
      $dist = acos(min(max($dist,-1.0),1.0)); 
      $dist = rad2deg($dist);
      $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
      $unit = strtoupper($unit);

      if ($unit == "K") {
          return ($miles * 1.609344);
      } else if ($unit == "N") {
          return ($miles * 0.8684);
      } else {
          return $miles;
      }

}
```

Now, I am trying to find out if two distances overlap or cross each other at any point and then return either true or false, like this:

[image]

Is there any easy way of achieving this? I've searched but cannot find anything even close to what I'm trying to achieve.

Maybe there's a really simple thing that I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

If this is always straight lines. Then we should use geometry
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection

or Vectors, than you should use `scalar vector multiplication`
https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-physics/chapter/vectors/

vectors if preferrable. They also give you an angle of interception, if you need it

Answer (score 0):

Check out this well documented solution by Martin Thoma with [code](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/tree/master/crossingLineCheck/Geometry/src) :

[How to check if two line segments intersect](https://martin-thoma.com/how-to-check-if-two-line-segments-intersect/)